# How to print user readable section of PlatformException from Firebase Login with Flutter?

Tags: firebase, error-handling, flutter

While working on my Login Page, I want to show a login error.  I'm successfully printing the following as `error`...

> PlatformException(sign_in_failed, FIRAuthErrorDomain, The email
>   address is badly formatted.)

How can I only print/show

> The email address is badly formatted

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not saying this is the best way to implement or I don't know whether this is the only way to do , but this is how I implemented it. Right now it works perfectly.

```
    void showErrorToast(String error) {
//I call this method if I got any error message from firebase authentication
        if (error.contains('email address is badly formatted')) {
          error = 'Check your email once..';
        }
        if (error.contains('no user record corresponding to this identifier')) {
          error = 'Hmm... no user found with this email.';
        }
        if (error.contains('password is invalid')) {
          error = 'oho... seems like your password is wrong';
        }
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: error,
            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
            gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
            timeInSecForIos: 1,
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            textColor: Colors.white);
    }
```

Comment: Perfect work around.  I was about to go for `error.toString().subString(53)`, which works but isn't as custom as your answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can print out all the error message as below:

Eg error: 
PlatformException(ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE, The email address is already in use by another account., null)

```
print(e);//as in above
print(e.code); //ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE
print(e.message);//The email address is already in use by another account.
print(e.details);//null
```